# How to integrate AdMob in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2, admob

On this stackoverflow question [AdMob BANNER is overlapping the bottom of the app view - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23476298/admob-banner-is-overlapping-the-bottom-of-the-app-view-android)

there is elaborated how to load AdMob in a Sencha Touch 2 app.

```
Ext.define("MyApp.view.Home", {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
xtype:'home',
config: {
    cls:'base',
    layout : 'card',
    items: [{
        docked:'bottom',
        cls:'home',
        name : 'tabBar',
        items:[{
            html: ['<div class="home-tab"><div class="left-tab"></div>',
            '<div class="tab-container">',

            '<div class="tab dash dashboard-tab activeClass" rel="dashboard"></div>',

            '<div class="tab test test-drive-tab" rel="test"></div>',
            '<div class="tab add" rel="add"></div>',
            '<div class="tab garage garage-tab" rel="garage"></div>',
            //                '<div class="tab garage ss-symbolicons-block ss-home" rel="garage"></div>',
            '<div class="tab engine engine-tab" rel="engine"></div></div>',
            '<div class="right-tab"></div></div><div class="tab-background"></div> '].join('')
        }]
    }, {
        xtype:'dashboard',
        layout : 'card'
    }, {
        xtype:'testtab',
        layout : 'card'
    }, {
        xtype:'addidea'
    }, {
        xtype:'garage',
        layout : 'card'
    }, {
        xtype:'engine'
    }],
    listeners: {
        painted: function() {
            setTimeout(function() {

                    var success = function() {
                        admob.requestAd({
                            'isTesting': false,
                            'extras': {
                                'color_bg': 'AAAAFF',
                                'color_bg_top': 'FFFFFF',
                                'color_border': 'FFFFFF',
                                'color_link': '000080',
                                'color_text': '808080',
                                'color_url': '008000'
                            }
                        },
                        successCallback,
                        failureCallback
                        );
                    };
                    var error = function(message) {
                        alert('Error');
                    };

                    var successCallback = function(el) {
                        alert(el);
                    //            alert('successCallback');
                    };

                    var failureCallback = function() {
                        alert('failureCallback');
                    };

                    var options = {
                        'publisherId': 'ca-app-pub-5476830338141***/9502253***',    
                        'adSize': admob.AD_SIZE.BANNER
                    }

                    admob.createBannerView(options, success, error);

            }, 2000);
        }
    }
   }
});
```

I installed the Plugin in Phonegap, put the above code in Sencha Touch, but I always get "Uncaught ReferenceError: admob is not defined".

Where in Sencha Touch do I have to load the plugin??

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of the plugin in https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova:

`phonegap local plugin add com.admob.google`

Hope this is the one you are using and I can help you (I'm not an expert in Sencha). Are you testing in a browser or in a moble phone/emulator?

Plugins in Cordova and Phonegap don't work in browsers and I guess it's almost the same in Sencha: they only work on emulators and devices as they use native features.